# Email client for windows, Android and Linux with sync

Tags: email, cross-platform, email-client

I am looking for a free email client with the following features:

- Usable on Windows, Android and Ubuntu-Linux, with about the same core functionality.
- Able to sync it's settings (and actions) between the two platform.
- "Snooze" emails, or attach a timed notification to them.
- Works with Gmail and IMAP4 or POP3.
- Relatively good-looking interface is a bonus!

The most known clients I know of (Thunderbird, Opera Mail, Outlook, etc.) all fail at the cross-platform requirement. Do you know any with these features?

If not, Windows+Android or Linux+Android ones are also in my interest.

Comment: Won't the Gmail Web client paired with the android app do?

Comment: @EdwardNunn Only Inbox can snooze emails AFAIK, but it has really limited functionality compared to Gmail. And it only supports Google Mail. But it's an option I'm considering as a last (but likely...) resort. (RN I use Inbox, and got really used to the snooze function...)